# How to get option as install zip from SD card in recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, sd-card

In a recovery mode, there are many options, such as:

- Apply update from SD card
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Wipe cache partition
- Backup and restore

But I can't find to install zip from SD card for installing zip file.

How to get option as install zip from SD card in recovery mode?

Comment: Are you using stock recovery?

Answer (score 1):

Recovery is of two types:
a. Stock recovery
b. Custom recovery

**Stock recovery** is the one that comes inbuilt in the phone (which you are using now)..
The "Apply Update" option in stock recovery is same as "Install Zip", except that you can install only official updates using stock recovery.

To install some other ROMs (OS) or for some other things like rooting (by flashing SuperSu or whatever), you have to first flash (install) a **custom recovery**.
The custom recovery can have the option you said: "Install Zip"

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the option to install zip from an SD card, then you're probably on your stock recovery which comes with your phone. Stock recoveries don't allow you to flash a zip file because the manufacturers don't want end-users to try it and end up with a soft-bricked phone.

You will have to install a custom recovery first. I recommend you install the latest version of TWRP recovery. To do this, search the procedure to install TWRP on your specific phone.

Comment: This answer could be improved by ascerting whether a TWRP build for the asker's device in fact exists and adding a link if it does. You could also add the recovery's installation procedure.